# Run multiple updates in a row | perl with oracle db

Tags: oracle, perl

everyone.

Is there a way to execute a bunch of UPDATES and INSERTS into a database in oracle in a row?

What I've got is something like that but it didn't work and didn't return a error message.

```
my $query = "UPDATE ...; UPDATE...; INSERT...;"
$sth = $db->prepare($query);
$sth->execute() or die $sth->errstr;
if ($sth->err){
    $content .= "error code: " . $sth->err . "msg:" . $sth->errstr;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `->do` instead of `->execute`?

Comment: @mob I tried $db->do($query); but it didn't work.

Comment: Try "BEGIN $query END;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  Per the [DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI):

> Multiple SQL statements may not be combined in a single statement handle ($sth)

I presume that this decision was made for reasons of security, to give additional protection from [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2):

One workaround would be to put your UPDATE/INSERT logic in a stored procedure, and call that stored procedure from Perl, with either `prepare` and `execute`, or (if you only need to call it once) `do`.